# Java Application script to display the number of rows in a column, of a SQL table. Error in SQL query. The output should be in a label

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

**Hello there. I am trying to get the result of my SQL query into a label on my java application. Any advice on what I am doing wrong? (The label is "lblTest", the table is "transactions" and the column in "TRANS_ID"). Thank you in advance.**

```
    try
    {
        conMySQLConnectionString = 
        DriverManager.getConnection
        (strDBConnectionString,strDBUser,strDBPassword);
        stStatement = conMySQLConnectionString.createStatement();
        String strQuery = "SELECT COUNT(TRANS_ID)"+"FROM transactions";
        stStatement.execute(strQuery);
        rs = stStatement.getResultSet();
        lblTest.setText(rs.getString(1));

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }
```

}

Comment: error clearly says it's error in the sql query

Comment: You may be missing a space between `TRANS_ID` and `FROM`

Comment: The result of the query won't display in the label.  "java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set"

Comment: @notyou I tried +"/n", did not work

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the resultSet contains at least one record :

```
if(rs.first()){
    lblTest.setText(rs.getString(1));
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I didn't know that!! This is correct.